# How to call a method with Context context

Tags: java, android, methods, android-context

Hello i found this method that creates a file and add strings in it

```
public void generateNoteOnSD(Context context, String sFileName, String sBody) {
try {
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs();
    }
    File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
    writer.append(sBody);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

My question is how to call this method ? i tried something like this

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String FILENAME = "hello_file";
    String string = "hello world!";
    generateNoteOnSD(Context ,FILENAME,string);
}
```

I don't understand the Context context part

Comment: call method like this generateNoteOnSD(this ,FILENAME,string);

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

you need to call the [getApplicationContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29) if you are in an Activity

```
generateNoteOnSD(getApplicationContext(),FILENAME,string);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
generateNoteOnSD(YoureActivity.this,FILENAME,string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 String FILENAME = "hello_file";
 String string = "hello world!";
 generateNoteOnSD(YourActivityName.this ,FILENAME,string);
}
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Fragment then do like this

```
generateNoteOnSD(getContext(),FILENAME,string);
```

if it is Activity do like this

```
generateNoteOnSD(YourActivityName.this,FILENAME,string);
```